# Property file in java

Tags: java, file, properties, resources, bundle

I want read property file in my java class.

for this i have written:

```
try {
            Properties property = new Properties();
            property .load(new FileInputStream("abc.properties"));
            String string = property.getProperty("userName");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i have placed my abc.properties file in same package where my java class resides. But i am getting FileNotFound exception.

Please let me know how to give path of property file.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 6):

The FileInputStream will look for the file in your program's "working directory", not in the same package as your class.

You need to use getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.properties") to load your properties file from the same package.

Comment: Surely that only works if abc.properties is actually in the default package? You need to request "my/package/abc.properties"

Comment: Nope, it will bve loaded relative to the Class which is represented by  getClass().

Comment: thanks....getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.properties") is working... but what will be path if i move my property file to WEB-INF ?

Comment: To load from WEB-INF, you need to use getResourceAsStream() from the ServletContext object.

Answer (score 1):

If the properties files is next to your class file, you should not use `FileInputStream`, but `Class.getResourceAsStream`.

```
 property.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.properties"));
```

This will even work when you package everything up as a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream. See this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html).

Answer (score 0):

let say ur class is TestClass then ur code must change to ,

```
InputStream input = TestClass.class.getResourceAsStream("abc.properties");
property.load(input);
```